# DF-Executor-OutOfMemoryError in synapse pipeline

Tags: azure, out-of-memory, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am having a json from ravenDB which is not valid json as it is having duplicate columns.
So my first step is to clean the json and if there are duplicates make separate json for each file.
I was able to do it for  sample file and it ran successfully,
Then I tried for a 12 MB file and it also worked.
But when I tried for a full DB backup file which is 10GB in size , it is giving error.

This 10 GB file generates 3 separate json as it is having DOCS columns 3 times.
First file is 9.6GB and other 2 files are small like 120MB and 10KB.
For the first file when I am trying to load it in Synapse DWH I am getitng below error.

Job failed due to reason: Cluster ran into out of memory issue during execution. Also, Please note that the dataflow has one or more custom partitioning schemes. The transformation(s) using custom partition schemes: Json,Select1,FlattenDocsCS,Flatten2,Filter1,ChangeDataTypesDateColumns,CstomsShipment. 1. Please retry using an integration runtime with bigger core count and/or memory optimized compute type. 2. Please retry using different partitioning schemes and/or number of partitions.

I tried to publish the pipeline so that I am not running in debug mode and in a small cluster.
I changed cluster size to 32 cores and changed partition schemes in optimize tab to all possible things.
But still I a getting an error.
Kindly please help

Comment: Also, when I am increasing the Cores of integration runtime to 64 , its giving below error. Internal Server Error:Failed to submit job on job cluster. Integration Runtime 'IR-Synapse-test', ActivityId: '410b7569-ff98-42cf-b8ca-a2e3ed30bae5

Comment: Constantly get this nebulous error with data factory. Each time its another piece of straw on the camels back to move to something more reliable.  The camels back is almost broken.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: As mentioned in the Error message :**

1. Please retry using an integration runtime with bigger core count and/or memory optimized compute type.

> Successful execution of data flows depends on many factors, including
> the compute size/type, numbers of source/sinks to process, the
> partition specification, transformations involved, sizes of datasets,
> the data skewness and so on.

**Increasing the cluster size:**

Data flows distribute the data processing over different nodes in a Spark cluster to perform operations in parallel. A Spark cluster with more cores increases the number of nodes in the compute environment. More nodes increase the processing power of the data flow. Increasing the size of the cluster is often an easy way to reduce the processing time.

MSFT Doc- Integration Runtime Performance | Cluster Size - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime-performance#cluster-size)

2. Please retry using different partitioning schemes and/or number of partitions.

**Note: Manually setting the partitioning scheme reshuffles the data and can offset the benefits of the Spark optimizer. A best practice is to not manually set the partitioning unless you need to.**

> By default, Use current partitioning is selected which instructs the
> service keep the current output partitioning of the transformation. As
> repartitioning data takes time, Use current partitioning is
> recommended in most scenarios. Scenarios where you may want to
> repartition your data include after aggregates and joins that
> significantly skew your data or when using Source partitioning on a
> SQL DB

MSFT Data Flow Tunning Performance : [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance#optimize-tab).

This will definitely contribute tunning your performance to next level. As the Error message has been well described.

Comment: I have tried all partitioning schemes and also set the optimization to Current Partitioning scheme as well. How much more cores should I use? It is already 64+16 cores and that too for just 2GB file. I even trie to just read the file and copy as it is in a csv and this too with setting all partitioning schemes available. Still no luck.

Comment: And one more thing , when I trying to increase core to 128 then getting below error. Means maximum I can increase is 64 cores.

{
    "errorCode": "134",
    "message": "Internal Server Error:Failed to submit job on job cluster. Integration Runtime 'D9F15919-6B5A-4194-98FE-B5D80B6B65B2', ActivityId: 'e27c34b8-8c98-425a-afd1-22a1ff83546a'.",
    "failureType": "SystemError",
    "target": "DF_Load_CustomsShipment",
    "details": []
}

Comment: @ShailendraKad - I'm also getting a similar issue please help me if you find the solution.

Comment: I'm encountering a similar issue. It seems like it's an issue with the data set size in my source. When the data exceeds 2GB, the job fails, regardless of cluster size. This makes me think there is a signed int somewhere behind the scenes that is overflowing... anyone solve this issue? @ShailendraKad did you get this to work eventually?

Comment: I somehow fixed it by reducing the size of json. one of the .net programmer wrote a code to partition the json in multiple small jsons(gzip) . Then I tried loading all the jsons. It worked for me.

Comment: We fixed this issue by separating big files into multiple smaller files(around 100 MB) and then loaded then simultaneously.