# Cluster ran into out of memory issue during execution, please retry using an integration runtime with bigger core count and/or memory optimized

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Trying to import 4.95GB mongodb table into Azure and even after using highest IR with max memory still throwing the above error

Expecting it to be resolved

Tried using multiple option in IR but didn't work

Comment: Need to provide more info, with what are you trying to import this to Azure? Are you using Copy Data in Synapse pipelines or code inside Synapse? If so you need to provide more information about this specific method you are using

Comment: We are using copy activity in Azure Data Factory and imported 4.95 gb from mongodb to datalake gen2. When trying to process this file using dataflow and store required data in azure sql. We are getting the above cluster error even we are using the highest IR configuration (256 +16 driver cores memory optimized)

Answer (score 0):

Specifically this should be DF-Executor-OutOfMemoryError. If not can you point out which DF- error code is this?

so First you copy the data to ADLS2 and then from there you are running a dataflow to transform it with azure sql as sink. Do you have a lot of joins or such expensive operations in your flow? Can you paste what operations you have in your dataflow?

Here is a few links that might help:

[DF-Executor-OutOfMemoryError in synapse pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69896806/df-executor-outofmemoryerror-in-synapse-pipeline)

[Integration Runtime out of memory ADF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70359786/integration-runtime-out-of-memory-adf)   (this link seems closer to your issue; You can try doing what he has done as solution)

Increasing cluster size might not be the solution in some cases. It can be partitioning problem

Note: Always try to do some search before posting a question. Usually your case would have been answered by someone already.

Comment: First of all thankyou for responding.

Second of all, no one will post before doing research and trying on their own.

I have done enough research and tried so many things out and then posted back here.

FYI, I have already tried those links before posting my issue here.

I am going to come up with a solution and post it back you.

Note: Don't be judgmental

Comment: @KulatejaMaraka, I didnt mean to be judgmental :) Lets see if fixing partitioning or breaking the data into smaller files would work for you